# Store links in Computer memory instead of excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to create web-scraper aka web-crawler to download PDF files from website. I would like to download all PDF files to `C:\temp\`. I have my links to sub pages on Excel sheet `A1:A17` currently.

They are grabbed to Excel worksheet with this code:

```
Sub GetAllLinks()

Dim internet As InternetExplorer
Dim internetdata As HTMLDocument
Dim internetlink As Object
Dim internetinnerlink As Object

Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

internet.Visible = False

internet.navigate ("https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/")

    Do While internet.Busy
      DoEvents
    Loop
    Do Until internet.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    DoEvents

    Loop

        Set internetdata = internet.document

        Set internetlink = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("a")

        i = 1

        For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink


            If Left$(internetinnerlink, 36) = "https://www.nordicwater.com/product/" Then

            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = internetinnerlink.href

            i = i + 1

            Else
            End If


Next internetinnerlink

End Sub
```

Code for file downloading:

```
Sub DownloadFiles()

    Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Dim bStrm
    Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim hAnchor As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wholeURL
    Dim link
    Dim range

    range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1:A17")

    wholeURL = "URL URL URL"

    sPath = "C:\temp\"

    For Each link In range

    'Get the directory listing
    xHttp.Open "GET", link
    xHttp.send

    'Wait for the page to load
    Do Until xHttp.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Put the page in an HTML document
    Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

    'Loop through the hyperlinks on the directory listing
    For i = 0 To hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Length - 1
        Set hAnchor = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Item(i)

        'test the pathname to see if it matches your pattern
        If hAnchor.pathname Like "*.pdf" Then

                Debug.Print wholeURL & hAnchor.pathname

                xHttp.Open "GET", wholeURL & hAnchor.pathname, False
                xHttp.send

                Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")

                With bStrm
                    .Type = 1 '//binary
                    .Open
                    .write xHttp.responseBody
                    .SaveToFile sPath & getName(wholeURL & hAnchor.pathname), 2 '//overwrite
                End With

                Set bStrm = Nothing

        End If

    Next i

    Next

End Sub
```

Function to get file name from url:

```
Function getName(pf)
getName = Split(pf, "/")(UBound(Split(pf, "/")))
End Function
```

wholeURL = "URL URL URL":

[image]

A1:A17:

[image]

etc.

How to connect these codes together so that there will be no need in using Excel Worksheet as link database and store links in Computer memory instead?

---

**EDIT:**

```
Sub DownloadFiles()
    Dim xHttp       As Object: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Dim hDoc        As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim Anchors     As Object
    Dim Anchor      As Variant
    Dim sPath       As String
    Dim wholeURL    As String

    Dim internet As InternetExplorer
    Dim internetdata As HTMLDocument
    Dim internetlink As Object
    Dim internetinnerlink As Object
    Dim arrLinks As Variant
    Dim sLink As String
    Dim iLinkCount As Integer
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim sLinks As String

    Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    internet.Visible = False
    internet.navigate ("https://www.nordicwater.com/products/waste-water/")

        Do While internet.Busy
          DoEvents
        Loop
        Do Until internet.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set internetdata = internet.document
        Set internetlink = internetdata.getElementsByTagName("a")

        i = 1

        For Each internetinnerlink In internetlink
            If Left$(internetinnerlink, 36) = "https://www.nordicwater.com/product/" Then

                sLinks = sLinks & internetinnerlink.href & vbCrLf
                i = i + 1

            Else
            End If

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("B1").Value = sLinks

    Next internetinnerlink

    wholeURL = "https://www.nordicwater.com/"
    sPath = "C:\temp\"

    arrLinks = Split(p_sLinks, vbCrLf)
    iLinkCount = UBound(arrLinks) + 1

    For iCounter = 1 To iLinkCount
    sLink = arrLinks(iCounter - 1)
        'Get the directory listing
        xHttp.Open "GET", sLink
        xHttp.send

        'Wait for the page to load
        Do Until xHttp.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'Put the page in an HTML document
        Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

        'Loop through the hyperlinks on the directory listing
        Set Anchors = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

        For Each Anchor In Anchors

            'test the pathname to see if it matches your pattern
            If Anchor.pathname Like "*.pdf" Then

                xHttp.Open "GET", wholeURL & Anchor.pathname, False
                xHttp.send

                With CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
                    .Type = 1
                    .Open
                    .write xHttp.responseBody
                    .SaveToFile sPath & getName(wholeURL & Anchor.pathname), 2 '//overwrite
                End With

            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
Function getName(pf As String) As String
    getName = Split(pf, "/")(UBound(Split(pf, "/")))
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the links in a string, separating each of them by `vbCrLf` and then use `Split(yourstring, vbCrLf)` to get an array of links. This way you don't need to run this in Excel or at least you don't need to use Excel cells.

To do so create a string variable, `sLinks` for example. Then, in your first loop, replace

`ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = internetinnerlink.href`

with

`sLinks = sLinks & internetinnerlink.href & vbCrLf`

Once this is done, you've eliminated storing the links in Excel. You can then pass this string as a parameter to your `DownloadFiles` sub:

```
Sub DownloadFiles(p_sLinks)
    Dim arrLinks As Variant
    Dim sLink As String
    Dim iLinkCount As Integer
    Dim iCounter As Integer

    arrLinks = Split(p_sLinks, vbCrLf)
    iLinkCount = UBound(arrLinks) + 1

    For iCounter = 1 to iLinkCount
        sLink = arrLinks(iCounter - 1)
        ' Process sLink here
    Next

End Sub
```

You can merge this code with your existing DownloadFiles sub, replacing the `For Each link In range` loop with the `For iCounter = 1 to iLinkCount`, putting the code from your loop inside this new loop and using `sLink` as the link to process instead of reading it from Excel.

You can break out some of your code into Subs to make it easier to read and troubleshoot:

```
Sub DownloadFile(p_sURL, p_sLocalPath)
    Dim xHttp As Object: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    xHttp.Open "GET", p_sURL, False
    xHttp.send

    With CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        .Type = 1
        .Open
        .write xHttp.responseBody
        .SaveToFile p_sLocalPath & getName(p_sURL), 2 ' //overwrite
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you again! I have added everything to one code, but there must be something I have understood wrong as it is storing the links into memory but not downloading files. I have added it to my question, so you can test yourself if you want.

Comment: Your updated code looks good as far as including the `sLinks` code. You have `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("B1").Value = sLinks` to check if the list is good? Your next troubleshooting step is to check how many items are in the `Anchors` collection and if any match the `Anchor.pathname Like "*.pdf"` condition. Please add more of this kind of information to your question so we can see how far it gets.

Comment: You can post a new question because this question is about _using Excel Worksheet as link database and store links in Computer memory instead_.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! I think troubleshooting the next step can be isolated to the code you have in your `For Each Anchor In Anchors` loop. You can extract that code to a Sub for easier troubleshooting and your next question can simply be that Sub since all the rest is working.

Comment: I have found the first problem, it was in `arrLinks = Split(p_sLinks, vbCrLf)` should be `arrLinks = Split(sLinks, vbCrLf)` but now I am getting another error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793436/loop-through-links-and-download-pdfs

Answer (score 2):

There were a couple errors in the code, I've corrected below. You need to create a new `ADODB.Stream` object, or, ensure you close the previous object. Also, you should strongly type the variables wherever possible. I cleaned this up in a few spots.

```
Function getName(pf As String) As String
    getName = Split(pf, "/")(UBound(Split(pf, "/")))
End Function


Sub DownloadFiles()
    Dim xHttp       As Object: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Dim hDoc        As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim Anchors     As Object
    Dim Anchor      As Variant
    Dim sPath       As String
    Dim wholeURL    As String
    Dim link        As range
    Dim range       As range

    Set range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1:A5")
    wholeURL = "https://www.nordicwater.com/"
    sPath = "C:\temp\"

    For Each link In range
        'Get the directory listing
        xHttp.Open "GET", link
        xHttp.send

        'Wait for the page to load
        Do Until xHttp.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'Put the page in an HTML document
        Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

        'Loop through the hyperlinks on the directory listing
        Set Anchors = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

        For Each Anchor In Anchors

            'test the pathname to see if it matches your pattern
            If Anchor.pathname Like "*.pdf" Then

                xHttp.Open "GET", wholeURL & Anchor.pathname, False
                xHttp.send

                With CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
                    .Type = 1
                    .Open
                    .Write xHttp.responseBody
                    .SaveToFile sPath & getName(wholeURL & Anchor.pathname), 2 '//overwrite
                End With

            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It can stay here, although I have figured it already myself. I can check this one and edit my current code.